# Tortoise Is very Slow And uses Huge amount of memory

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Since some days TortoiseSVN uses lots of memory when I want to commit also it takes 10 - 20 minutes before the changed files appear.
On normal use it doensn't use much memory only when commiting or comparing changed files.

As you can see the memory usage is not normal.

I have already reinstalled the newest version (1.8.10) but no difference.

Does anyone have any clue?
(the directory I am working in is 2 GB This includes the tempdata witch is excluded from svn and i am working on w7 x64)

[image]

Here is a Screenshot of the Icon Overlay settings i use

[image]

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the memory usage **grow** (3-4 minutes): http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa

Comment: Are you using TortoiseSVN in shared drives? That's a big, fat, ugly, nasty, evil no-no. It causes the symptoms you've specified here: Slow, massive amount of memory used, etc.

Comment: In the TortoiseSVN configuration, go to Icon Overlays and make sure the icon overlays are unchecked for Network Drives

Comment: I have working copies in the nearly 2GB range and they don't ever use that much space. I suspect you've got a buggy copy of TortoiseSVN installed (can you upgrade to the latest? Or try re-installing what you have?) or have some corrupted data in your working copy and need to run `SVN Cleanup`. Can you run the corresponding `svn` commands from the command line without issue?

Comment: @magicandre1981 i will do this when i am at work on monday.

Comment: @DavidW.  I am using it in a local drive so not shared network drive. And as i can remember i already do that but i will try when i am at work.

Comment: @joey Although using a shared drive will. Definitely  slow down TortoiseSVN. It's not only using a shares drive or local drive, but whether this icon overlay setting for shared drives is on or not. If you have a shared drive mounted, and had it open, it can greatly slow down TortoiseSVN because TSVN still tries to track the state of possible SVN working directories.

Comment: @DavidW. unfortunatly that doesn't work. I added the settings they already where this way except the cache was at default. (rest i edited alreary before.)

Comment: @alroc with command line no isues at all. It justs commits.

Comment: @joey Reboot machine. Kill and restart `explorer`? 2Gb is pretty big, and that could be causing problems. Is it possible to use a _sparse checkout_, or do you need all the files in this directory?

Comment: @DavidW. We need all the files. But the strange thing is that my colleges doens't have these problems. And they have even slower computers with the same checkout. And restart done many times. I think i have to get used to it.

Comment: Something is going on with your computer. Is there something running on it that is not on a coworker's machine? Do you have some sort of software on it that someone else might not have? Maybe you can get a new machine. What happens if someone accidentally spills coffee on it, or it accidentally falls off the roof?

Comment: @DavidW. the only thing i know is that i have Resharper and they dont. The rest no and i dont think resharper can cause this issue.

Comment: Wait, if you're using Resharper, why not use [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net)? It integrates directly into VisualStudio, and should be faster than TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Because i have to use VisualSVN (I know it doesn't mather for svn but my boss wants it that way) and visualSVN uses tortoiseSVN when i want to commit

Comment: have you captured the trace of the memory usage grow?

Comment: Yes i have but it is to big to upload i will do that when I get home.

Comment: compress it as 7z/RAR to reduce the size

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue since I updated to (TortoiseSVN 1.8.10); excessive amounts of memory used and a each refresh of your view would increase this amount even further.
The new version 1.8.11 appears to have resolved the issue.